# How can I return the number of videos in a YouTube playlist using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm embedding a YouTube playlist and want it to play a random video on every page load.

How do I find the number of videos in a playlist using JavaScript or JQuery so that i can use javascript to select a random number between 0 and the total number of videos?

```
<div class="vid"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PL82F269F11AB50FA4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Comment: assuming that you have jQuery on your page, and it has the alias $, this should work: $('li[data-index]').length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using Youtube Api V3 , not sure if you can do it using the `<iframe>` method , however please refer to [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list)

You can find in Request Body method which will return a JSON:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    playlistItem Resource
  ]
}
```

where items is an `array` , fetching the array length will indicate the items count using `array.length`.

In the following demo use these data to fetch items in the playlist suggested in your question , scroll down till you see the `Try it` , you can leave all fields as blank but `part` should be filled as `snippet`,`maxResults` as `50` , and `playlistId` should be filled as `PL82F269F11AB50FA4` which is your Playlist ID.

and Here is a screen shot of the result:
[image]

you can see that total results are 93 , and details are stored in items array.

items found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELfUpXoP-A4&list=PL82F269F11AB50FA4) are 93 items.

**[DEMO](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#try-it)**

Comment: Thanks! After setting up an API key and pinging YouTube, I was able to parse the response and get the "totalResults" value. I used JS to pick a random number between 0 and the total and then put that at the end of the playlist url in the iframe. "&index=the random number". So now the embed code shows a different video from the playlist on every page load.

Comment: showing a random video is an issue or was it done on purpose ?